# How to host multiple web app in GCE in 1 VM instance

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

Hi I have 1 vm instance in GCE (Google Cloud computing engine) and I want to host mutliple web apps or websites. do I need subdomain for each of my web apps ? I tried to create subdomain and pointing to other web app folder but it will always call to my first web app which I created in default nginx because it uses static ip. is this possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add your nginx conf

Comment: Related gist: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a separate nginx configuration file for each sub domain. each sub domain is called a server block which is same as an apache virtual host. It has its own document root and host name. See this link on how to configure server blocks in nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3